# IntelliJ code style option FORMATTER_TAGS_ENABLED

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

I have an IntelliJ (xml) code style file with an option named FORMATTER_TAGS_ENABLED but can't find out what it does:

```
<option name="FORMATTER_TAGS_ENABLED" value="true" />
```

I've tried to search through the IntelliJ IDEA Community [repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) for how the option named in the UI, how it's read from the code style file but can't find a matching String literal (i.e. `"FORMATTER_TAGS_ENABLED"`). Despite that, there's a variable `com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.CodeStyleSettings#FORMATTER_TAGS_ENABLED` initialized in `com.intellij.application.options.GeneralCodeStylePanel#apply`, but I can't find to what the associated checkbox is initialized to.

Could someone point me in the right direction, maybe even to what the option does? Or was it perhaps renamed/deleted in a previous version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option corresponds for **Enable formatter marker in comments** in Settings(Preferences) | Editor | Code Style.